# Merge two queries in one single query in django

Tags: django-queryset

I have a model as follow:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    base = models.Boolean(default=False)
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

In ModelB we have records as below:

```
id          name           base        modela
------------------------------------------------
1          solution_base    True        X2ZQ
2          solution_x       False       X2ZQ
3          solution_base    True        ALSB
4          solution_z       False       ALSB
5          solution_base    True        5YET
6          solution_c       False       5YET
7          solution_base    True        PIAT
...        ...              ...         ...
```

As you can see each record has a base copy of itself that can be distinguished by unique modela foreignkey. All I need, is that by a given normal solution id(example `solution_x`) I need to query its base equivalent base object (where modela ids are the same). Here what I did so far:

```
modela_id = ModelB.objects.filter(id=modelb_pk).select_related('modela_id').values_list('modela_id', flat=True)
modelb_solution_base_id = ModelB.objects.filter(modela_id=modela_id[0]).filter(base=True).select_related('modela_id').values_list('id', flat=True)
```

I guess there should be a solution to merge these two using `prefetch_related(Prefetch())` but I have no idea how to use that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this a bit more complicated than necessary -- the Django ORM handles much of this for you, thanks to that foreign-key relationship. Given an ID for ModelB, the ID for the other ModelB with the same ModelA but where base=True is just:

```
 ModelB.objects.get(id=modelb_pk).modela.modelb_set.get(base=True).id
```

Why does this work?

1. Because ModelB has a many-to-one relationship with ModelA, we can call `.modela` on an instance of ModelB to get the corresponding ModelA.
2. Conversely, given an instance of ModelA, calling `.modelb_set` returns all ModelB records associated with ModelA.
3. We can then call `.get`/`.filter` on `modelb_set` just like we would with `ModelB.objects`.